# Tab to show directory contents

Tags: bash, autocomplete, cd-command

I use the terminal app on OSX.  Whenever I cd into a deep directory I find it useful to display the successive directory contents as I go.  By tapping tab when typing the filepath, it lets me see the current directory.  For whatever, reason it takes 3 tab taps to get this to work.  The second tab makes the operating "beep" sound play.  This is simply annoying.  Somebody showed me this feature but perhaps I am using it incorrectly?

Comment: For bash, search for `show-all-if-ambiguous`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use tab in bash (which is the shell used by default on OSX), it first tries to complete what you have typed up to now, then show non-ambiguous completion, then (third tab) all completions.

You can change this behavior by creating a file named `.inputrc` in your home directory, and put in it:

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

This will remove the 'ambigous' step and the corresponding beep.
For more options, see: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html

To further improve completion usage on mac, you can also use the `FIGNORE` variable to automatically skip some files, for example:

```
export FIGNORE=.DS_Store
```

will automatically exclude `.DS_Store` files from the complexion.

Comment: works perfectly!